# Delphi7: cannot load JPEG from record, but can load it from database directly

Tags: delphi, blob, jpeg, record

First of all, I am using the following record:

```
type
  TCarouselPhotos = record
    cpDescription:  String;
    cpDurationSec:  Integer;
    cpPhotograph:   TJPEGImage;
    cpOrder:     Integer;
  end;
```

This record is used in the following array:

```
CarouselPhotoArray: array of TCarouselPhotos;
```

And now I am trying to load data from the database into this array:

```
CarouselPhotoArray[0].cpPhotograph:= getImageFromBlob;
```

And this is the function I am using:

```
function TFormMain.getImageFromBlob: TJPEGImage;
var tmpStream: TMemoryStream;
    tmpJPEG: TJPEGImage;
begin
  tmpStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  tmpJPEG   := TJPEGImage.Create;
  try
    TBlobField(QueryTemp.FieldByName('Afbeelding')).SaveToStream(tmpStream);
    tmpStream.Position := 0;
    tmpJPEG.LoadFromStream(tmpStream);
    If tmpStream.Size > 0
      then Result := tmpJPEG  // note: when I try "image1.picture.graphic := tmpJPEG" it works!
      else Result := nil;
  finally
    tmpStream.Free;
    tmpJPEG.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Somehow I do not get any errors, but as soon as I try to display the picture it will raise an access violation error...

```
Image1.Picture.Graphic := CarouselPhotoArray[0].cpPhotograph;
```

What can go wrong here? Please help.

Comment: You're assigning the result of `getImageFromBlob` to your carousel record, but you call Free on tmpJPEG so the carousel record is pointing to free'd memory.  Doing `Result := tmpJPEG` doesn't create a copy of the JPEG object.

Comment: Should I just remove the line which is freeing up the memory or should I solve this another way to make it work and being clean?

Comment: Well, there are several ways to go about this, but as the JPEG in each CarouselPhotos record needs to be kept alive while the record is in use, removing the `tmpJPEG.Fee` line would be the most straightforward.  YOu would need some code to free each CarouselPhotos.cpPhotograph when it is no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks ! I have fixed it the way you initially described.

Comment: Whenever you have a function that is returning some object as an result you should not be freeing that object from within the function itself. Lifetime of the object in question needs to surpass the execution time of the said method therefore freeing the object within the said method is out of the question. . But you still need to destroy the said object after you have done using it. In such cases this will be done sometime after your function has been executed.

Comment: It was a wrong idea to have these objects destroyed before they even were used… thanks for the explanation!